# rpi3 distro optimized for linuxsampler

Tags: pi-3, audio

I am going to have a stroke trying to compile a rt-kernel and I'm just not proficient enough to accomplish this task in a timely fashion.

Can someone please direct me to a rpi3 distro that will run linuxsampler with reasonable latency? I'm looking to just flash a copy of someone's SD card. I've wasted way too much time here and am fed up.

---

Edit #1 (to include what research I've done so far in the matter):

I had http://www.samplerbox.org/ running on my device but found the latency to be too high, especially noticeable in the lower octaves. (Which is to be expected, but it is where RT seems to really shine). I tried cross compiling per the instructions on https://github.com/dddomin3/DSPi , but it failed to build although I paid exacting attention to detail to the tune of 5 hours yesterday).

I tried another set of build instructions and then bricked my device this morning, which compelled me to ask the community for help.

---

Edit#2: I am currently setting up a zynthian build, per Matt's helpful recommendation below, and following up with the guidance from the forum post he linked to. I will provide another edit of my results after testing that.

Comment: Please don't link to https://autostatic.com/

Comment: Perhaps you could show some of the reseach you have done!

Comment: Currently compiling https://github.com/gbevin/erpiam to see if I can get linuxsampler going on top of that.

Comment: I have kxstudio dual booted on my desktop, but there are no rpi3 compatible builds of that... I'm looking for something out of the box that would run linuxstudio... as that does.

Comment: *"Which is to be expected, but is where RT seems to really shine"* -> Strongly implies you have witnessed performance "in the lower octaves" demonstrating this claim (that a realtime kernel will make it "really shine"), although the rest of your question kind of implies that in fact you have no such frame of reference.  I'm raising the issue because I worry you have latched onto a concept ("realtime kernel") which you assume is a solution to some problem, but have have no real evidence to support the assumption.  Which this is one I think is often made, and often wrong...

Comment: A further illustration of wishful thinking: "I have kxstudio dual booted on my desktop...I'm looking for something out of the box that would run linuxstudio [on a pi 3] as that does".   Unless your desktop is a decades old antique, you will never, ever, ever be able to compile a kernel that will make an Rpi 3 capable of anything even close to your desktop performance wise.  Is not going to happen.  Do not chase the rainbows here.

Comment: The rpi3 has specs comprable to my dell xps 420 running a core 2 duo from 10 years ago which I had running VST's at 44.1/16bit sub 5ms latency. So, I hope you feel good about yourself, but please get off your high horse, be helpful and stop being condescending.

Comment: If by "specs" you mean processor frequency, keep in mind that the ISA for an Intel core 2 is not the same as it is for an ARM processor, and one of them is more optimized for performance than the other -- but good luck to you sir!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73309/discussion-between-gino-l-and-goldilocks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a low latency thread on our forum. One recommended distro is the
[Zynthian OS](https://github.com/guysoft/ZynthianOS).

If you want to read more about low latency and the Pi w.r.t. what others have tried and use, then check [this forum post](http://forum.audioinjector.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2727).

Comment: Thank you so much for the recommendation and the link, I really appreciate it!